# Automatic disabled MS Access From textbox

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a user form in an `MS Access Application` that I developed 20 years ago that I'm trying to revamp. The problem is that I cannot figure out how some controls on a subform are being disabled. I have looked through every line of code on the form and the subform and cannot figure it out.

[image]

The selected text indicated a category of item and if the item ends in man-hours values, it enables the 6 controls on the left (3 textboxes and 3 labels), if it ends in something other than man-hours it enables the controls on the right. This all works correctly, but there is no code that I can find that is changing these values. Is there a way to trace all event procedures that are being triggered by this combobox change? (It is not any of the combobox event procedures listed in the code).

I have searched the entire project for the word enabled, locked, and "for each" in case I had disabled it in another obscure manner, but this does not appear to be the case. I'm really stumped.

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: Have you looked at the property sheet (tab Events) for the combobox in Form Design view? A public function may be called directly with `=SomePublicFunction()` e.g. in the AfterUpdate event.

Comment: @Andre yes, I have looked at all the events associated with the controls on that subform. It is displayed as a continuous subform, so some of the form instances have one set selected while the others have the opposite selected. When building a new record the disabling of one set of the controls is tied to selecting data in the combobox, but it is not in any of its events.

Comment: Thank you @vlad-dekhanov for the edits, I'm a long time lurker, but new poster.

Comment: @Boris15er you are welcome!:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it looks like I'm a dummy, the controls are disabled through conditional formatting, which I never thought to look at.

Comment: Good find. :) *some of the form instances have one set selected while the others have the opposite selected* - this is a sure indicator for conditional formatting, since it can't be done with VBA in a continuous form.